# I have nested lists as entries to a Python dictionary. How do I print the nested list whose first elements is "S"?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {(1,0): ['A', 'B'],
           (1,1): [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]],
           (1,2): [],
           (2,1): [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]], [['S'], [[[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]], [[['G'], [['H', 'J'], [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]]]]]]]]]
           }
```

How do I retrieve the first sublist I find that begins with ['S']? For the example above I would like to get:

```
answer = [['S'], [[[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]], [[['G'], [['H', 'J'], [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]]]]]]]]
```

I don't know how deep the 'S' is nested.

EDIT:

I attempted to do it recursively as follows:

```
def recursive_check(longlist):
    for a_list in longlist:
        if 'S' in a_lis:
            return a_lis
        else:
            rec_check(a_list)
```

I received the following error:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

EDIT: The list may look different and be nested differently every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def first_s(lst):
    if not (isinstance(lst, list) and lst):
        return None
    if lst[0] == ['S']:
        return lst
    else:
        for x in lst:
            y = first_s(x)
            if y:
                return y
```

Using your `my_dict`:

```
>>> print first_s(my_dict.values())
[['S'], [[[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]], [[['G'], [['H', 'J'], [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]]]]]]]]
```

Comment: I attempted to do it recursively in a similar way earlier. I'll add it to my post. Alas, I received the following error: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @Michi That is a tricky issue.  Note that there are lines in my code to stop the recursion before that happens.

Answer (score 2):

To get that list:
`answer = my_dict[(2,1)][1]`

It first gets the dictionary value with key of `(2, 1)`, then takes that value (which is a list) and gets its item at index 1, which is the second item in the list (after 0).

```
>>> my_dict = {(1,0): ['A', 'B'],
...            (1,1): [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]],
...            (1,2): [],
...            (2,1): [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]], [['S'], [[[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]], [[['G'], [['H', 'J'], [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]]]]]]]]]
...            }
>>> my_dict[(2,1)][1]
 [['S'],
 [[[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]]],
 [[['G'], [['H', 'J'], [[['E'], [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'F']]]]]]]]]
```

(By the way, in your example, you are missing a comma after `(1,2): []`

...Update: which has now been fixed :) )

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The dictionary may be different every time. I'm asking how to access the list that contains ['S'] in the most general case, not for that specific example.

Comment: It did answer your question, in fact. You should have mentioned in the question that the dictionary may be different every time. That information changes the problem quite a bit. In programming it's very important to be precise.

Comment: I see that at least one other person (Mahesh24) interpreted the question in the same way that I did.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not clarify.

Comment: No problem. Looks like John1024 figured it out, and all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 2):

You can print element of s like `my_dict[(2,1)][1][0]` .

Answer (score 0):

```
def nest(a,x):
    m=False
    for i in a: 
        if type(i)==list:
            m=nest(i,x)
        else:
            if i==x:
                return True
        return m


def our_fun(my_dict):
    for i in my_dict:
        for j in my_dict[i]:
            if nest(j,'S')==True:
                return my_dict[i]
```

I checked for 'S' recursively.